# How can I remove text(e.g ["88664734","88639280","88676217"]) from a strReviewers string using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove text(e.g ["88664734","88639280","88676217"]) from a strReviewers string which contains list of Reviewers separated by semicolon and then join the whole string again either using JavaScript or jQuery?

I get a dynamic string(strReviewers) which contains multiple user records separated by comma:

I need to remove whole user record if I pass an array of ids. e.g ["88664734","88639280","88676217"]

```js
var strReviewers = "88664734*,*Andrew Farmer*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19051,*;*88639280*,*Sally Hopewell*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*88686221*,*Jonathan Rees*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19060,*;*88676217*,*James Wason*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*";
```

strReviewers contains user records separated by semicolon and each user record is separated by *,*.

Each record contains 1 user which is in the shape of userid then following by name then following by roleid then following by txtSpeciality following by then rolelist.

```js
/*
88664734*,*Andrew Farmer*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19051,*;
*88639280*,*Sally Hopewell*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;
*88686221*,*Jonathan Rees*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19060,*;
*88676217*,*James Wason*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;
*/
```

I have done it using the following code but wondering this can be achieved some other easier way?

```js
var strReviewers = "88664734*,*Andrew Farmer*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19051,*;*88639280*,*Sally Hopewell*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*88686221*,*Jonathan Rees*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19060,*;*88676217*,*James Wason*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*";
function removeReviewerByID(ids = []) {
   return strReviewers
        .split(";")
        .map(item => item.split("*,*"))      
        .filter(item => item[0] !== "*")
        .map(item => ({
          userid:item[0],
          name:item[1],
          roleid:item[2],
          txtSpeciality:item[3],
          rolelist:item[4]
        }))        
        .filter(item => (!ids.includes(item["userid"]) && !ids.includes(item["userid"].replace(/\*/g, ''))))
        .map(item => ({
          record: item["userid"].concat("*,*").concat(item["name"]).concat("*,*").concat(item["roleid"]).concat("*,*").concat(item["txtSpeciality"]).concat("*,*").concat(item["rolelist"]).concat(";")
        }))
        .reduce((accumulator, item) => {  
          return accumulator.concat(item["record"]);
        }, "")        
}

console.log(removeReviewerByID(["88664734","88639280","88676217"]));
```

Comment: If you want a review of your code, check [the help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/) to see if your question can be made on topic for [codereview.se]. As it is, you'll need to define "easier" in some objective way (fewer lines of code, perhaps?) for this to be on topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to use a regular expression. Turn the array of IDs into a pattern by joining by `|`, and then filter for records that don't start with the pattern.

To keep the data structure consistent, consider using `.match(/.*?\*;\*/g)` instead of `.split(";")` - by matching, you'll be preserving the formatting (where the first item doesn't start with a `*`, and where the final item is terminated by `,*;*`)

```js
var strReviewers = "88664734*,*Andrew Farmer*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19051,*;*88639280*,*Sally Hopewell*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*88686221*,*Jonathan Rees*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19060,*;*88676217*,*James Wason*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*";

function removeReviewerByID(ids = []) {
  const pattern = new RegExp(`^(?:${ids.join('|')})\\*`);
  return strReviewers
    .match(/.*?\*;\*/g)
    .filter(str => !pattern.test(str))
    .join('');
}

console.log(removeReviewerByID(["88664734", "88639280", "88676217"]));
```

It would be possible to do it in a single regular expression replacement, though it'd be more confusing.

```js
var strReviewers = "88664734*,*Andrew Farmer*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19051,*;*88639280*,*Sally Hopewell*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*88686221*,*Jonathan Rees*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19060,*;*88676217*,*James Wason*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*";

function removeReviewerByID(ids = []) {
  const pattern = new RegExp(
    String.raw`(?:^|(?<=\*;\*))(?:${ids.join('|')})\*.*?\*;\*`,
    'g'
  );
  return strReviewers.replace(pattern, '');
}

console.log(removeReviewerByID(["88664734", "88639280", "88676217"]));
```

`/(?:^|(?<=\*;\*))(?:88664734|88639280|88676217)\*.*?\*;\*/g` means:

- `(?:^|(?<=\*;\*))` - Match either

  - `^` - Start of line, or
  - `(?<=\*;\*)` - A position preceded by `*;*` (the start of a reviewer section)
- `(?:88664734|88639280|88676217)` - Match any of the IDs
- `\*` - Match a literal `*` (make sure the ID ends here)
- `.*?` - Match any characters, lazily, until encountering
- `\*;\*` - The characters `*;*`

This approach matches and removes the delimiter between reviewers at the end of each match.

Comment: Txs, very smart, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short and sweet answer using a `.split()`, `.filter()`, and `.join()`:

```js
var strReviewers = "88664734*,*Andrew Farmer*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19051,*;*88639280*,*Sally Hopewell*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*88686221*,*Jonathan Rees*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19060,*;*88676217*,*James Wason*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*";
var excluded = ["88664734","88639280","88676217"];
var excludedRegex = new RegExp('\\*?(' + excluded.join('|') + ')\\b');
//var excludedRegex = new RegExp(excluded.join('|'));
var result = strReviewers
  .split(';')
  .filter(item => !item.match(excludedRegex))
  .join(';');
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
*88686221*,*Jonathan Rees*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19060,*;*
```

Explanation:

- the `excludedRegex` is the regex representation of the `excluded` array
- the filter returns false on a  regex match, e.g. an exclude

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```js
var strReviewers = "88664734*,*Andrew Farmer*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19051,*;*88639280*,*Sally Hopewell*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*88686221*,*Jonathan Rees*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,19060,*;*88676217*,*James Wason*,*19042*,**,*,19013,19017,19042,19043,*;*";
var excluded = ["88664734","88639280","88676217"];
var result = strReviewers
  .split(';')
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let userid = curr.split('*,*')[0].replace(/\*/, ''); //remove * from userid
    if(!excluded.includes(userid)) {
      acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .join(';');
console.log(result);
```